# Anythingslider questions - Caption positioning

Tags: jquery, css, anythingslider

I am currently battling with the anythingslider jquery - https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki, I have almost managed to make it do what I want!

Heres where I am at so far - http://jsfiddle.net/Cm479/3281/

- For some reason the first caption is not displayed, if you go forward a slide and then back then the caption is displayed correctly.
- I want the caption to display at the bottom on the slide itself, overlaying the image.  Currently it is sitting below the slider and I cant work out how to get it to move up.
- I have managed to add a button called 'Show / Hide Caption' and it works correctly, clicking it toggles the caption.  I am trying to get the tab itself to float to the right but have not been able to manage it.

Can anybody can help with any of the above questions?

Comment: Note: AnythingSlider has been moved from ProLoser's account to CSS-Trick's account: https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki

Comment: this may help as well http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/5262/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I answered your [question over on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/15518/anythingslider-moving-caption-location) sufficiently, but you never responded. I provided [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/5262/)... so, is there something wrong with it? Or did you need something else?

Edit: Updated demo

Comment: Hey Mottie, all of the questions on this subject seem to lead to you.  However none of the associated jsfiddles seem to be working.  It's like the .js isn't linked up anymore or something.  I am trying to get some captions under my anything slider.  Can you point me somewhere with working captions I can dig into ???  Thanks !

Comment: I just noticed an example on the demo page in the FX section.  That should do the trick.  ★

Comment: Yeah, we moved the AnythingSlider repo over to [CSS-Tricks](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider), so all the old demos are broken but should still work if you update them with the correct URL to the plugin. I have updated all of the demos in the documentation. Sorry for the inconvenience!